# The most DB efficient way of retrieving one field of a random ManyToManyField relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have these 2 models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Video(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('home.Tag', blank=True, related_name='tags')
    thumbnail_link = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

In a `Video` listview I want to get 15 random tags, so I use this code:

```
class VideoListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Video
    context_object_name = 'video_list'
    template_name = 'pages/home.html'
    paginate_by = 12

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        tags = Tag.objects.all().order_by('?')[0:15]

        context['tags'] = tags

        return context
```

So far so good, I can iterate over the 15 tags in my template.

```
{% for entry in tags %}
   {{ entry.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But what I want to do now is get 1 random `thumbnail_link` of an associated video of a particular tag in my for loop.

What works is this:

```
{% for entry in tags %}

     {% for image in entry.tags.all %}

         {% if forloop.first %}
             {{ image.thumbnail_link }}
         {% endif %}

     {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

But I feel this is very unefficient for the database because you generate an extra for loop in a loop, and you retrieve too much unneccessary data. Also it is too much template logic, I would rather move that to the view.

What is the most db efficient way to get the `thumbnail_link` of one random `Video` that has a relationship with the `Tag` that is getting looped over?

Answer (score 0):

`Tag.objects.prefetch_related('tags').order_by('?')[:15]`

Check it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: Nice thankyou! But then in the second loop there is still 15 `Video` items and all there related fields each time you loop over `Tag`. But I only need `thumbnail_link` and then one random entry.

Is there no other way to achieve this?

Comment: @RafRasenberg well then you need to query ```Video``` instead and make it ``distinct```